# Copy & Paste doesn't work

Tags: macos, keyboard, high-sierra, copy-paste

After updating latest patch on High Sierra 10.13 on a 2012 MacBook Air, I can no longer copy and paste text. I restarted computer, booted into safe mode, tried copy and pasting in various applications like Textedit. If I do 'cut', the text goes away but clipboard in Finder shows it's empty.

Activity Monitor shows pboard and pbs processes exist. I killed it and a new one appears with same problem. The problem happens using keyboard shortcuts as well as using menu. When I do `Command-c`, The Edit menu blinks blue while I do that. Drag and drop text works fine. Mouse keys are turned off. I don't have virtualbox. I don't have Copied or additional clipboard software installed.

How can I determine what the problem is? This was working fine yesterday.

Update: Copy and paste was fixed by restoring from Time Machine backup. Reapplying the same High Sierra patch worked fine after that.

Comment: There was an answer that was deleted but seemed useful pointing to [How to reset NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

Comment: I have the same problem, but resetting NVRAM did not help.

Answer (score 1):

From [this Apple Support discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7679531)

> So, to fix a stuck clipboard (pasteboard) problem, you simply need to:
>
> 1. Open your application folder
> 2. Open the utilities subfolder
> 3. Open the Activity Monitor app
> 4. Type “pboard” into the search box at the top right
> 5. In the search results below, there should only be one result — a row listing the “pboard” process. Highlight it by clicking on it.
> 6. Click the “x” button at the top left of the window which represents ‘quit this process’
>
> Once you’ve done that, OS X will kill the faulty PBoard process and
>   re-establish it with a fresh one automatically. Your clipboard should
>   be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Clear system caches, which is done when booting in safe mode; sometimes a corrupt system cache is the cause, and just restarting in safe mode and again restarting normally fixes problems.

Comment: I already booted in safe mode and restarted numerous times. Same problem.

Comment: You may need to backup your files and reinstall the software.

Comment: I’m doing a time machine restore from a couple of days ago. Hopefully that’ll work. As a Windows user for 25 years who recently switched to Mac I really can’t believe I lost copy and paste ability by updating the OS.

Comment: It happens when doing updates from time to time. A full restore tends to fix issues like this. Whenever you update regularly you're patching the previous software and adding layers to it. With a fresh install, there are no extra layers from the old software still on the computer.