# How do I kill pboard from command line?

Tags: terminal, activity-monitor

I'm sick of [manually killing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301228/copy-paste-doesnt-work) the pboard process in Activity Monitor to recover my copy & paste.

Is there a Terminal Command I can run instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `killall pboard`. That should kill it. I'm not sure it restarts by itself, though.